# iOS7 Tabbar icons too big

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uitabbarcontroller

Seems I am having difficulty with something as simple as icons.

I am building an app for iOS7 only and thus, devices are retina displays (excluding iPad 2). So I made up some 60 x 60 icons for my tabbar. However these are just too big. And 30 x 30 is a little pixelated.

Here is what a 60 x 60 icon looks like:

[image]

Can someone tell me why this is happening?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/BarIcons.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH21-SW1

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Keep 60x60px icons but rename them as iconName@2x.png which iOS will automatically reduce to 30x30 points, roughly to half of the original size on retina devices.

If you are using assets catalogue, please make sure your icons are set to 2x icon sets.

Comment: Ah crap - since I haven't worked with Xcode 5 and the asset catalogue - I forgot to set them as 2x images. THANK YOU

Answer (score 0):

Or you can do something like this:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.jpg"];

[image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30)];

first.tabBarItem.image = image;
```

Comment: I get errors in the log when I try this:  <Error>: CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.